# Installing Gimp plugin in ubuntu(xenial)

Tags: ubuntu, installation, plugins, gimp

I wanted to install the [Wavelet decompose addon](http://registry.gimp.org/node/11742) in my ubuntu studio, but, the plugin Contains a bunch of make files and .c files, and the install intructions are given which I cannot really understand:

```
INSTALL
=======

For Linux and Unix users
------------------------
To install this GIMP plugin simply state

    make
    make install

for a system wide installation (with root privileges) or

    make
    make userinstall

for a user installation. A restart of The GIMP is recommended.
```

I tried navigating to this folder and hitting commands on the terminal, but gives me a lot of errors:

```
make -C po
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/dell-pc/Desktop/wavelet-decompose-0.1.2/po'
msgfmt -c -v -o de.mo de.po
de.po:7: warning: header field 'Language' missing in header
17 translated messages.
msgfmt -c -v -o ru.mo ru.po
ru.po:2: warning: header field 'Language' missing in header
17 translated messages.
msgfmt -c -v -o it.mo it.po
it.po:9: warning: header field 'Language' missing in header
17 translated messages.
msgfmt -c -v -o pl.mo pl.po
pl.po:2: warning: header field 'Language' missing in header
17 translated messages.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/dell-pc/Desktop/wavelet-decompose-0.1.2/po'
make -C src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/dell-pc/Desktop/wavelet-decompose-0.1.2/src'
make[1]: gimptool-2.0: Command not found
cc -O3 -Wall  -c -o plugin.o plugin.c
In file included from plugin.c:12:0:
plugin.h:16:26: fatal error: libgimp/gimp.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:19: recipe for target 'plugin.o' failed
make[1]: *** [plugin.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/dell-pc/Desktop/wavelet-decompose-0.1.2/src'
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'src' failed
make: *** [src] Error 2
```

I then again, tried moving this raw folder to my plugins folder, it didn't install. How do I install this plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To install many Gimp plugins in Ubuntu, just install the gimp-plugin-registry package from the repositories (this done using: `sudo apt install gimp-plugin-registry`) (and yes, it contains the wavelet decompose, plus other useful ones: the resynthesizer, liquid rescale, FFT... ).

Otherwise, to install the plugin 'the hard way': your messages indicate that you are missing the `gimptool` executable as well as `gimp.h`. `apt-file search {file}` shows that both files are in package `libgimp2.0-dev`, so all is needed is `sudo apt install libgimp2.0-dev` to install that package.

If you want up-to-date versions of Gimp and related packages (including gimp-plugin-registry) you can add [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/ubuntu/gimp) to your software sources, and then issue `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install gimp` to upgrade the package.

Comment: Can we install gimptool-2.0 externally? It's not in /usr/bin.

Comment: `gimptool` comes with package `libgimp2.0-dev` (which is somewhat coherent, since it needs the Gimp includes...)

Comment: which means I've got to install libgimp2.0-dev?? I don't understand.

Comment: do you mean this?(https://pasteboard.co/GBkmEvg.png)

Comment: but it's only for windows

Comment: @BeshalJaenal Yes: `sudo apt install libgimp2.0-dev` to go the hard way and install the plugin form source, or `sudo apt install gimp-plugin-registry` if your prefer living a simpler life by installing packaged software.